# Using Value objects in react select

Tags: react-select

I am trying to use values of objects for the select options:

> option:1 {label: "Age-5", value:{name:"Age", value:"5"}}. option:1
>   {label: "Age-5", value:{name:"Age", value:"5"}}. option:1 {label:
>   "Age-5", value:{name:"Age", value:"5"}}.

But When the options are chosen, they don't get matched against the selected values 
image

I have tried `valueRenderer` option too, but can't quite get that to working. Any pointers to fix this is much appreciated.

Comment: Using a value object as a value in an option works just fine. What are you expecting and where?

Comment: Got this resolved..  I had to change the format of the value saved and that fixed it.